# visual c++ why does std::move crash

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, stdvector

I want to append a vector to the end of another vector. According to my knowledge, the function `std::move()` is the "function of choice" for this task. Why is `std::move()` from Microsoft Visual C++ Express crashing while a hand-crafted loop works as expected?

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Update 3. Unfortunately I'm not able to test this with other compilers.

```
// The setup code for the two vectors:
vector<unique_ptr<channel>> channels, added_channels;

// ...  here is some code that adds some elements to both vectors
```

According to my knowledge the following two pieces of code should work the same way. They should move the elements of `added_channels` to the end of `channels`.

This is the first variant that crashes:

```
std::move(added_channels.begin(), added_channels.end(), channels.end());
```

This is the second version that works:

```
for(auto & ref : added_channels)
{
    channels.push_back(std::move(ref));
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is trying to move the elements past the end of the vector which is an out of bounds access. `std::move` is designed to move to an already initialized range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually one of the few cases where a `move_iterator` is actually useful:

```
channels.insert(channels.end(), 
                std::make_move_iterator(added_channels.begin()), 
                std::make_move_iterator(added_channels.end()));
```

For insertion into a `vector`, range `insert` is preferable to element-by-element `push_back` (or the equivalent `back_inserter`) because it avoids unnecessary reallocations and correctly grows the storage exponentially. The latter is easy to mess up: indiscriminate uses of `reserve` can easily cause quadratic behavior.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your answer is brilliant. It goes beyond my initial question and even addresses the performance concerns of the other answer. (The other answer is equally well correct)

Answer (score 13):

std::move moves into the the specific location.
If you want to insert it to the back of the vector, you should use [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

```
std::move(added_channels.begin(), added_channels.end(),  std::back_inserter(channels));
```

Comment: @bolov, I don't need erase, I discard the other vector.

Comment: As these are both vectors, I would recommend using `std::vector::reserve` to avoid multiple reallocations.

Comment: @patatahooligan, You are absolutely correct. But performance is not a concern at the present time. I may become one in the future.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer, sorry, I've un-accepted your answer because I really think that T.C's answer deserves to be accepted. Your answer is correct too - but T.C's answer helps code clarity and performance.